# add event listener with jquery to generated dynamycally href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic-html

I have many href generated dynamically with php, and i need event listener click.

it´s no very much problem, but when i´m traying to do click in one, always returned me, same data.

i have this:

```
$(".qrCode").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();

      $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('restaurants.qrcodes', $id) }}",
        type: "GET",
        success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

            alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

            alert('Requested page not found [404]');

          } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

          } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

          } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

            alert('Time out error.');

          } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

            alert('Ajax request aborted.');

          } else {

            alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

          }
        }
      });
  });
```

my html is:

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{trans('lang.restaurant_qrcodes')}}" href="{{ route('restaurants.qrcodes', $id) }}" target="_blank" class='btn btn-link qrCode'>
      <i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i>
    </a>
```

**update**

[image]

but i need if i want to do click in href witch id 12 go to id 12, now always go to id 11. I think that i can to do a `each` but i don´t know how i can do it.

I need this, for to do, a loader gif while web do operations

Thanks for help

Comment: from where are you getting value `$id` ? please elaborate more and show html as well.

Comment: it´s in blade Laravel, update my question

Comment: change `url: "{{ route('restaurants.qrcodes', $id) }}"` to `url: $(this).attr('href')`

Comment: with this, if i do click in href with id 12, i get 12¿?? update my question for add image of my result, i need only one

Comment: Add images ? Sorry , i am not able to understand what you trying to achieve here .

Comment: @Swati i need that If i'm to do click in one link generate data with this id. I atached one img where you can ser my resulta with your code. I did click in id 17 and repeat 4 and of i click in id 29 also repeat. I need only one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227982/discussion-between-swati-and-daviserraalonso).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With method unbind() i get that i can only can select one href that i would like it

Solution:

```
$(".qrCode").unbind().click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  });
```

Comment: Please explain answers rather than simply dumping code.